# Docker compose keeps network up after containers stop

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, continuous-integration, docker-network

My CI/CD runs tests using docker compose. I use `--abort-on-container-exit` option so compose stops all the containers once the test container has finished.

However it seems that networks created by compose are still up. This is an issue, as we quickly reach the networks definitions limits in Docker.

I looked at the documentation for a way to remove the networks once the containers exit, but I couldn't find anything. I think I could just do a `docker-compose stop`, but that doesn't fit well with my Jenkins pipeline.

Is there a way to achieve this either through `docker-compose up` options or in the compose manifest ?

Comment: you can create an system cronjob and run `docker network prune -f`

Comment: You’re right and that’s what I am doing right now but I was looking  at a solution where I was pruning only the networks created running the last docker compose run. If there is no such option in docker compose run I’ll stick to this solution

Comment: Do you also remove the containers? Would `docker-compose down` be an option here?

Comment: Yes I guess that could be an option

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue. Indeed, `docker-compose down` solves it.